# How to draw fullscreen without blurring the graphics?

Tags: xna

The screen dimensions are 320x240 - when this is displayed fullscreen the sprites are blurred - I want to display in a retro (blocky) style.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When calling `Begin()` on your sprite batch, use a sampler state with point filtering: either `SamplerState.PointWrap` or `SamplerState.PointClamp`.